# create different sliders by clicking different buttons (matplotlib widgets)

Tags: matplotlib, button, widget, slider, visible

Okay, here we go: This code first defines 3 different sliders (f010,f015,f022) that are set invisible and 3 different buttons (WR10,WR15,WR22). Tje sliders are all at the same xy position. Then each button should call a specific slider, e.g. Button WR10 --> slider f010. The problem is, that if one button is clicked, all 3 sliders are called and do overwrite each other. Can someone help me?

```
from __future__ import print_function
from numpy import pi, sin
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from matplotlib.widgets import Slider, Button, RadioButtons
from matplotlib.patches import Ellipse
from scipy.optimize import fsolve

#Plot
axis_color = 'lightgoldenrodyellow'
fig = plt.figure(figsize=(20,10))
ax = fig.add_subplot(111)
fig.subplots_adjust(left=0.25, bottom=0.35)

#Define Sliders and set all invisible
f010_slider_ax = fig.add_axes([0.25, 0.25, 0.65, 0.03], axisbg=axis_color)
f010_slider = Slider(f010_slider_ax, 'f0_10 [GHz]', 750.0, 1100.0, valinit=750.0)
f010_slider_ax.set_visible(False)

f015_slider_ax = fig.add_axes([0.25, 0.25, 0.65, 0.03], axisbg=axis_color)
f015_slider = Slider(f015_slider_ax, 'f0_15 [GHz]', 500.0, 750.0, valinit=500.0)
f015_slider_ax.set_visible(False)

f022_slider_ax = fig.add_axes([0.25, 0.25, 0.65, 0.03], axisbg=axis_color)
f022_slider = Slider(f022_slider_ax, 'f0_22 [GHz]', 340.0, 500.0, valinit=340.0)
f022_slider_ax.set_visible(False)


#Define WR buttons
WR10_button_ax = fig.add_axes([0.025, 0.9, 0.05, 0.05])
WR10_button = Button(WR10_button_ax, 'WR1.0:', color=axis_color, hovercolor='0.975')

WR15_button_ax = fig.add_axes([0.025, 0.8, 0.05, 0.05])
WR15_button = Button(WR15_button_ax, 'WR1.5:', color=axis_color, hovercolor='0.975')

WR22_button_ax = fig.add_axes([0.025, 0.7, 0.05, 0.05])
WR22_button = Button(WR22_button_ax, 'WR2.2:', color=axis_color, hovercolor='0.975')


#Define Event on Buttons
def WR10_button_on_clicked(mouse_event): 
    f010_slider_ax.set_visible(True)    
WR10_button.on_clicked(WR10_button_on_clicked)

def WR15_button_on_clicked(mouse_event):
    f015_slider_ax.set_visible(True)
WR15_button.on_clicked(WR15_button_on_clicked)

def WR22_button_on_clicked(mouse_event):
    f022_slider_ax.set_visible(True)
WR22_button.on_clicked(WR22_button_on_clicked)


plt.show()
```

Comment: You will need to make your axes distinguishable. `WR10_button_ax = fig.add_axes([0.025, 0.9, 0.05, 0.05], label="bla1")`, `WR15_button_ax = fig.add_axes([0.025, 0.8, 0.05, 0.05], label="blubb2")` etc.

Comment: This is close to what I want, BUT:
If I want to change the sliders they do not react. There is no blue marked area and the value is not changing. More details:
I can create the three different sliders by clicking on the respective buttons. For that I used your labeling and your visible False or True command. I defined each slider to work on a function. But only the last defined (f022) slider changes the value by dragging. If I click on the other buttons, the respective slider is created but I cant change the value. There is no blue marked area anymore.

Comment: Strange. But again, just show the non-working code in the question, such than one can understand what you're doing.